# How database Transaction work with application code

Tags: python, mysql, sql, transactions

Suppose we have following pseudo python code to deal with Mysql:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "SELECT `count` FROM `sometable` WHERE `name`=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('somename',))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result['count'] == 1:
        sql = "UPDATE `sometable` SET `count`=%d WHERE `name`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (10, 'somename'))

connection.commit()
```

I know transaction will provide an "all-or-nothing" proposition, but don't know how it works if mixed with application code. How can database transaction deal with appliction code like: `if result['count'] == 1`.

In my understanding, when committed, all sqls will be handled to Database Server to execute, and the server will make sure sqls execute "all-or-nothing". But the code above should only execute the `UPDATE` sql when `count` equals `1`. What would happen if all the sqls have already handled to the database server and some other transaction just change the `count`?

Comment: I suspect that you are really asking if transaction prevent race conditions. See [Do database transactions prevent race conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6477574) if that was your real question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are right, the link you gave me just explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transaction includes any changes made to the database. If application code tests prevent changes from being made, they are not part of the transaction. So if `result['count']` is not equal to `1` no changes have been made, because you never sent the `UPDATE` command to the database.

See transactions as a 'todo list' you hand to the database, and `commit` tells the database to go do that list. Your `if` test simply controls wether or not you write down the update on that list. The database doesn't have to care *how you wrote the list*.

If you were looking for ways to prevent the `UPDATE` from taking place if another transaction also updated the database *in parallel*, then you'll need to eiher look into locking strategies (creating an exclusive lock to force whole transactions taking place in a series) or to detect that the row has been changed during the transaction with optimistic locking. See [Do database transactions prevent race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477574/do-database-transactions-prevent-race-conditions).

For your specific case the latter would look like this:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "SELECT `count` FROM `sometable` WHERE `name`=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('somename',))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result['count'] == 1:
        sql = "UPDATE `sometable` SET `count`=%d WHERE `name`=%s and `count`=1"
        cursor.execute(sql, (10, 'somename'))
        if cursor.rowcount != 1:
            # another transaction updated the row already. Handle this gracefully.
            # you could elect to roll back here.
```

The `rowcount` after the `UPDATE` would be 0 if the row with the matching `name` column has already been altered to have a different `count` value; we were selecting for `count=1`, after all.

Comment: @realli: to what end? Even if you moved this to a database stored procedure you wouldn't be protected from another transaction colliding.