# Django get updated items

Tags: sql, django, django-models, race-condition

There is a queue of tasks for humans. I want to take one unfulfilled task from the queue and assign an executor. I use `update()` and nested query to prevent a race condition.

```
sliced_queryset = Tasks.objects.filter(done=False, executor__isnull=True)[:1]
task = Tasks.objects.filter(id__in=sliced_queryset).update(executor=request.user)
```

`update()` returns the number of rows matched. I want to have updated object in `task` variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Well usually a view is wrapped in a single transaction if I recall correctly, hence first querying then updating should be safe, since other views work with another transaction. If you do the database queries in a transaction, then they only take *effect* when you end the transaction. So in your view it looks like the transactions are done, but other concurrent transactions can not influence that.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6477574/67579

Comment: Do you want the *number* of rows updated, or the rows itself?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `Well usually a view is wrapped in a single transaction ` is that true?

Comment: @itzMEonTV: given the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` setting is set to True: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests