# Generate different Unique IDs using SELECT rows by ID

Tags: php, mysqli

It's a php mysqli query where there is a table named result(uid,matchid,playerid,score)
I want to generate a unique id based on number of rows returned by the select statement with matchid
That would look something like this
if matchid is 0 then on first the rows returned would be zero then uid must be 
matchid+rows returned
and then saving data with that uid and match id with other details

I hoped it must return something like this...
i.e. if id1(ID) is 0
then the unique id(UID) would be
ID+UID
that is 00,01,02...and so on where the UID would increment based on number of rows returned with the specific id1(ID).

another example, taking a different ID
i.e. if id1(ID) is 1
then according to the above explanation 
it would be
ID+UID
i.e. 10,11,12...and so on based on the number of rows returned by that id1(ID)

I have tried to get the number of rows returned by the match id and found that the result given was 0(must indicates null),and scound time it also returns 0 and after the third time it starts incrementing values.
i.e 00,00,01,02 and so on

```
<?php

$ri=0;
$res=mysqli_query($c,"select rsid from result where mid='$m' ");

$rows=mysqli_num_rows($res);

$ri=$rows++;

echo ("<script> alert( '$ri' ); </script>");

//Unique Match Id for Player Result
$rsid = $m.$ri;

//Saving the data in the table
mysqli_query($c,"insert into result values('$rsid','$m','$u','$k','$w')");

?>
```

I expected the output to be 00,01,02...
but the output is 00,00,01,02...

Comment: This question is an exemplary xy problem

Answer (score 0):

To produce your desired results, you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax with a `COUNT` subquery on the `result` table, in order to retrieve your row count or 0, along with a `CONCAT()` of the `mid` to produce the desired `rsid` value.

To help prevent SQL injection attacks, it is strongly encouraged to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php),

Assuming `rsid` is your primary key you can use the following.

### Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6grnCCPmrhRhmrsK2vxmsd/0)

```
//enable mysqli exception handling
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$c = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

$query = <<<'EOL'
INSERT INTO `result`
SELECT 
CONCAT(?, COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(r.rsid)
  FROM `result` AS r
  WHERE r.mid = ?
  GROUP BY r.mid), 0)), 
?, ?, ?, ?
EOL;

try {
   /* example data
    *  $m = 0;
    *  $u = 1;
    *  $w = 1;
    *  $k = 1;
    */
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($c, $query)
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', $m, $m, $m, $u, $k, $w);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    /*
     * retrieve the theoretical last record inserted
     */
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($c, 'SELECT MAX(rsid) FROM result WHERE mid = ?');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $m);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $rsid);
    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo $rsid;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
   //handle the exception
   //echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Results per execution

```
| execution | $rsid |
|     1     |  00   | 
|     2     |  01   | 
|     3     |  02   |
...
```

---

> **Disclaimer**, your current approach of using the total number of rows to generate the `rsid` is subject to serious data integrity complications. When a
>   record is deleted from the `result` table, the retrieved `COUNT` or `mysqli_num_rows` will result in a conflicting `rsid`. Additionally if the `mid` value is ever changed (a typo is corrected), the `rsid` value will become invalid.
>
> There are also additional complications to consider with [race conditions/hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). 
> See [sql - Do database transactions prevent race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081833/1144627) for details on preventative measures

For example, if you have a record of `00` in the database already, `SELECT CONCAT(mid, COUNT(rsid)) WHERE mid = 0;` will return `01`. After inserting `01` and then removing `00`, your next insert will be a duplicate `rsid` of `01`;

```
INSERT INTO results(rsid)
VALUES(01);
DELETE FROM results WHERE rsid = '00';
INSERT INTO results(rsid)
VALUES(01);  /* error duplicate key */
```

---

I recommend using `SELECT MAX(rsid) + 1` instead of `COUNT()`.  This will ensure your `rsid` is not repeated after deletion, but does not resolve the `UPDATE mid` issue. **However you will need to have a minimum `mid` of 1 for `MAX() + 1` to work**.

### Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dmfBEYVwkN6UWWtYbGU3Eo/1)

```
INSERT INTO `result`
SELECT 
COALESCE((SELECT MAX(r.rsid) + 1
  FROM `result` AS r
  WHERE r.mid = ?
  GROUP BY r.mid), CONCAT(?, 0)), 
?, ?, ?, ?
```

---

If you absolutely need to use row count, to avoid the complications, you would need to ensure to only `DELETE` the highest `rsid` record within the `mid` grouping, and never `UPDATE` the `mid` column values. Otherwise you will need to rebuild all `rsid` values, on any change to the table. If you decide to rebuild the `rsid` values, I suggest using before update and after delete [`triggers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) to handle both of these instances and use a `DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` column to determine the ordering of the records.

---

Alternatively you could generate an `rsid` only when viewed, by using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key and an incremental user variable. Then you no longer need to worry about the application controlled `rsid`, and only be required to insert the `mid`.

### Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4A66yGZ1vU7nfGLwTkUxUK/0)

```
SET @rsid: = NULL;
SET @mid = NULL;
SELECT 
    result.*,
    CONCAT(mid, CASE WHEN @mid != result.mid OR @rsid IS NULL THEN @rsid := 0 ELSE @rsid := @rsid + 1 END) AS rsid,
    @mid:=result.mid
FROM result
ORDER BY mid ASC, id ASC;
```

Result

```
| id  | mid | ... | rsid |
| 1   |  0  | ... |  00  |
| 29  |  0  | ... |  01  |
| 311 |  0  | ... |  02  |
| 20  |  1  | ... |  10  |
| 40  |  1  | ... |  11  |
...
```

---

As a last alternative, you can use a segmented `AUTO_INCREMENT` by specifying a composite primary key of `mid, id` with the MyISAM engine, which is *not* capable of transactions or foreign key references. However, there are additional complications with this approach. [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html#example-auto-increment-myisam-notes)

> `AUTO_INCREMENT` values are reused if you delete the row with the biggest `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in any group.

### Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/prw8YY6EJ4yXWjggeLsP8U/0)

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
    `mid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`mid`, `id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
;

INSERT INTO result(mid)
VALUES(0),(1),(0),(2),(0),(1);

SELECT
   result.*,
   CONCAT(mid, id) AS rsid
FROM result;
```

Results:

```
| mid | id  | rsid |
| --- | --- | ---- |
| 0   | 1   | 01   |
| 0   | 2   | 02   |
| 0   | 3   | 03   |
| 1   | 1   | 11   |
| 1   | 2   | 12   |
| 2   | 1   | 21   |
```

To update your current `result` table you can use

```
/* remove default value */
ALTER TABLE `result` ALTER `mid` DROP DEFAULT;

/* change engine, add id column, add composite primary key */
ALTER TABLE `result`
ENGINE=MyISAM,
CHANGE COLUMN `mid` `mid` INT(11) NOT NULL FIRST,
ADD COLUMN `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `mid`,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`mid`, `id`);
```