# After one transaction is committed,second one must be updated about the first one?

Tags: mysql, database

I started two transactions at same time in mysql.

After updating one transaction and commited it, in second transaction I still get the old value instead of updated value.

What is the reason for that?

I inserted a new row in to a table in T1.After commited the first transaction,Here in T2,it doesnt show the newly inserted row in T1(by select * from table command).Since i committed the first transaction shouldn't  second transaction give the updated value?

```
T1
start transaction;
insert table1(id,name)values(5,'new name);
commit;

T2:
start transaction;(This transaction is started at the same time when t1 started.)
select * from table1;(this has done after commit the T1);
```

enter code here

Comment: Can you please expand? What were the transactions? What did you check?

Comment: @Uberhumus  sure.I have edited my question.Thank You!

Comment: I think you might need to re-edit. I doubt it looks like you intended.

Comment: sorry for that.I have re edited.Im a beginner for this and sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: It's OK, this is how we learn. Now, as for the actual question, please explain how you know that the 2nd one isn't executed before the 1st one (In the answer).

Comment: oh !!!it means we cant guarantee that which transaction is executed first in concurrent transactions?Therefore,we have to commit all transactions.is it?

Comment: You're in a good direction, now if I were you I would do a few things. I would time each transaction (several times if possible) to see which is quicker. If the 2nd transaction is repeatedly quicker you have your answer. If it's dynamic you can add a delay in the 2nd transaction. Also I would read more about SQL race conditions, over here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477574/do-database-transactions-prevent-race-conditions and then I would write an answer to my own question. :)

Comment: @Uberhumus Thankyou very much for your kind guidelines!!!!Thank You again!!!